# Setting a class on selected rows after updating cell data

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am doing a batch update on cell data by looping through selected items/rows. I want my rows to have a class added after my batch update to show that they have been modified. Is this possible? I've been trying to manually set edit mode.

Comment: Check out [ask] and [mcve] and then come back to edit your question appropriately.

Comment: Agree with @Lex. To answer your question, why dont you try to add a variable which tells whether the row was updated or not and then set your ng-class to use that variables to show the row as selected.

Comment: Nilesh's solution worked.

Answer (score 0):

I set a variable State to a string "changed"

```
var selecteditems = $scope.subapi[key].selection.getSelectedRows();
angular.forEach(selecteditems, function (value, key){
  selecteditems[key2].State = "changed";
});
```

in the row template i use ng-class:

ng-class="{ 'row-text-red': row.entity.State=='changed',  }"